# Error installing mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install `mysql-server php5-mysql phpmyadmin` but I'm running into the following error:

```
 An error occurred while installing the database:

 mysql said: ERROR 1006 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'phpmyadmin' (errno: 2)
```

This is my 3 attempt to install it but every time I try I get errors. I was able to install just `phpmyadmin` but when I go to users I get another error #1064.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I removed a large part that cluttered the error message. But the "'phpmyadmin' (errno: 2)" was a bit TOO much :X

Answer (score 0):

"errno 2" is a directory or file related problem that probably means your MySQL configuration is not correct.

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` check `datadir` for a valid directory and that this directory holds your databases and that you can write to that directory. You can do the 1st with

```
grep datadir /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and the 2nd with

```
ls -l {datadir}
```

where {datadir} is the value you get from the 1st command.